# MySQL Opposite of Left Join

Tags: mysql

I have a table A and table B.
The relationship between A and B is one to many.
Now I want to make a select over all elements of A, whose primary key are NOT registered by B as a foreign key.

```
Select u.Id from A as u LEFT JOIN B as c ON u.id IS NULL WHERE u.active='1'
```

This query does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a ANTI JOIN:

```
SELECT u.ID
FROM
  A as u LEFT JOIN B as c
  ON u.id = c.a_id -- join with the correct key/foreign key
WHERE
  u.active='1'
  AND c.a_id IS NULL
```

this will return all IDs from table A where there's no corresponding key in table B.